# Extremely slow initial connection to nginx on Vagrant?

Tags: nginx, vagrant

I running an Ubuntu VM via Vagrant on a Windows 10 host. On the Vagrant machine I am running a fairly standard PHP/nginx app.

Whenever I try to access the web app, it takes forever to load. Chrome network inspector shows this:

[Chrome network timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ypUO.png)

This huge latency is completely gone on subsequent requests, but whenever I pop back into the browser and try again after a while, it crops up yet again.

- I am using NFS.
- I have disabled firewalls on both guest and host machines.
- I increased `keepalive_timeout` in nginx which helped hide the problem, as it increased the time window for latency-free subsequent requests.
- This latency occurs even when accessing static files, so I don't think it's a PHP-FPM/MySQL problem.

Comment: how are you using NFS? Windows dont support that. Which version of ubuntu do you use? Have you tried shared folders?

Comment: @GorillaApe I am using the [winnsfd](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd) plugin. Ubuntu 14.04. Also tried standard shared folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully figured out what my problem was!

After looking at my Windows `hosts` file, it looked like my [`vagrant-hostmanager`](https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager) plugin had not been properly clearing out older IP entries (i.e. I had three seperate IP entries for `myapp.dev` even though only one IP was active). Probably because I'd forgotten to properly `vagrant halt` before shutting down my PC a few times.

Windows was clearly spending ages trying to resolve the two older entries before successfully resolving the 'real' one.

It's weird: you'd think this problem would cause the latency to show up in the `DNS Lookup` portion of the Chrome network timeline, rather than `Initial connection`, but oh well!

Comment: I have a same problem. how can I fix that problem? is that key `vagrant-hostmanager`??